# does calling a repaint() inside paint() lead to infinite recursion?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I have been developing a java application related to graphics . From my understanding everytime i use the repaint() method anywhere in the code , the overridden paintComponent is called . But i have also used repaint() inside the paintComponent itself .why is it not leading to infinite recursion ? the code works fine .

```
              panel = new JPanel(){
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {

            {

                panel.revalidate();
                panel.repaint();
                c.revalidate();
                c.repaint();
                revalidate();
                repaint();
                for(int i=0;i<linecount-1;i+=2)
                {
                    Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(xco[i],yco[i],xco[i+1],yco[i+1]);
                    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                    if(divide[i]==1)
                    {

                    //System.out.print(xco[i]+" "+yco[i]);
                    //System.out.println();

                     g2d.setStroke(drawingStroke);
                     g2d.draw(line);
                     g2d.setStroke(simple);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        g2d.setStroke(simple);
                        g2d.draw(line);
                    }
                    //g.drawLine(xco[i],yco[i],xco[i+1],yco[i+1]);
                }

                //g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
                panel.revalidate();
                panel.repaint();
                c.revalidate();
                c.repaint();
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        }
    };
```

}

Comment: Robin Green is correct: you should not be calling repaint (or revalidate) from within paintComponent.  paintComponent may be called very frequently and needs to be lightweight and fast.  It appears you aren't changing any state in your paintComponent method anyway.  The revalidate call (which I'm pretty sure will call repaint for you) should immediately follow whatever code actually changes your component's state.

Comment: Not in the sense that you are thinking about it, but it will chew through your system resources very quickly, bringing your system to it's knees within a minute or two.

Answer (score 5):

It does not lead to infinite recursion - on the Java stack - because repaint merely schedules a new paint to be done, it doesn't actually call `paint` or `paintComponent` immediately.

However it's still a bad idea to do this.